# NullPointerException, Calculator Program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've run into a snag in my Java PostFix calc program that I have thus far been unable to fix. In particular, this program results in a NullPointerException, and I can't figure out why. Without further ado, here it is.

First is the tokenizer class, which parses a space-delimited string into string tokens (in theory, anyway).

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class Tokenizer {

      private Queue<String> tokens;

      public Tokenizer(String input){
           loadString(input);
      }

      public void loadString(String input){
         tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
         String[] toks = input.split(" ");
         for (String s : toks){
             tokens.add(s);
         }
      }

      public Iterator<String> getIterator(){
          return tokens.iterator();
      }
 }
```

And here is my calculator class..

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class calculator {

      private static Stack<String> myStack;  // to be accessed by static method

      private static final Set<String> operators = new HashSet<>();
      static {
          operators.add("+");
          operators.add("-");
          // and others
      }

      public static boolean isOperator(String token){
          return operators.contains(token);
      }

      public static float performOperation(String operator, float f1, float f2){
          switch(operator){
              case "+":
                  return f1 + f2;
              case "-":
                  return f1 - f2;
              // and others
          }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Operator");
       }

       public static float calculate(String expr) throws IllegalArgumentException{
           float result;
           Tokenizer t = new Tokenizer(expr);
           Iterator<String> myIterator = t.getIterator();
           //Begin Calculation
           while (myIterator.hasNext()){
               String myToken = myIterator.next();
               if (!isOperator(myToken)){
                    myStack.push(myToken);
               }
               else {
                   float f1 = Float.parseFloat(myStack.pop());
                   float f2 = Float.parseFloat(myStack.pop());
                   result = performOperation(myToken, f1, f2);
                   myStack.push(result);
               }
               result = Float.parseFloat(myStack.pop());
               return result;
       }
  }
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at PostfixCalculator.calculate(PostfixCalculator.java:103)
at PostfixCalculatorTest.calculate(PostfixCalculatorTest.java:30)
```

Line 103 is myStack.push();
Line 30 is empty

Comment: can u paste error strack trace

Comment: how do I do this on Netbeans?

Comment: Post the stack trace.  Also tell us which line the null pointer is.  The stack trace should be in the console where the output of the program usually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize the myStack variable to a valid object. You could do this with,

```
myStack = new ....;
```

---

But more importantly than the specific problem with your code, you will want to learn how to go through the process of debugging a NPE (NullPointerException).

- Find the line that throws the NPE.
- The stackTrace will tell you exactly which line, for example in your case it is `PostfixCalculator.java:103` == line 103 of your PostfixCalculator.java class.
- if you use an IDE, such as NetBeans or Eclipse or IntelliJ, the IDE will often be able to quickly and easily bring you to that offending line by double clicking on the stack trace.
- Check all the variables on that line.
- One of those variables that you are trying to dereference (usually by calling a method) is null. Find out which one.
- Track back into your program to see why it is null.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialize the stack, initialize as below :

```
Stack<String> myStack= new Stack<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you initializing `myStack`, so it could only be `null`.